# replace textbox with div with jquery not working

Tags: jquery

It's just working for a few seconds and then the div disappears again:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#done").click(function () {
        $('#txtname').replaceWith(function () {

            return '<div>' + $(this).val() + '</div>';
        });
    });
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3XrCx/.

Comment: This builds markup from user input without using `html()` or `text()`. If the value of `txtname` contains characters like `<` or `&`, the resulting markup may be invalid and `replaceWith()` would not behave as expected.

Comment: you probably have another script causing the problem.

Comment: you're also missing a close bracket `});`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `ID` if `this` not works

```
$("#done").click(function() {
    $('#txtname').replaceWith(function() {

        return '<div>' + $("#txtname").val() + '</div>';
    });
});
```

and here is another example if above not works

```
$("#done").click(function() {
    $('#txtname').replaceWith('<div>' + $("#txtname").val() + '</div>');
});
```