# replace textbox with a div with jquery not working

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace textbox with div with jquery not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550986/replace-textbox-with-div-with-jquery-not-working)

**It's just working for a few seconds and then the div disappears again:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#done").click(function () {
        $('#txtname').replaceWith(function () {

            return '<div>' + $(this).val() + '</div>';
        });
    });
```

**.aspx**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" BorderColor="#96A6C5" CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox></div>

<div class="text">
<asp:Button ID="done" runat="server" onclick="done_Click"/>
</div>
```

**.cs**

```
protected void done_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: This is probably because a click on the asp:Button causes a postback to the server and therefore resets your markup. Why do you have the button hooked up the done_Click method on the server side? Do you wan't something to happen on the server? If you don't, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683746/how-to-disable-postback-on-an-asp-button

Answer (score 0):

The script part should work fine. But I think there is a problem in the way you are accessing the controls.

`$("#done")` and `$("#txtname")` should really be `$("#<%=done.ClientID%>")`
 and `$("#<%=txtname.ClientID%>")` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `ID` if `this` not works

```
    $('#<%=done.ClientID%>').click(function() {
        $('#<%=txtname.ClientID%>').replaceWith(function() {

            return '<div>' + $('#<%=txtname.ClientID%>').val() + '</div>';
        });
return false;
    });
```

and here is another example if above not works

```
    $('#<%=done.ClientID').click(function() {
        $('#<%=txtname.ClientID%>').replaceWith('<div>' + $('#<%#txtname.ClientID').val() + '</div>');

return false;
    });
```